# Is there a decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional logic?

Tags: logic, algorithms, intuitionistic-logic, provability, decidability

Is intutionistic propositional logic decidable?  If so, what is a decision procedure for it, like tableaux for classical propositional logic?

EDIT: In the first revision I mistook "predicate" for "propositional".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there cannot be a decision procedure for intuitionistic predicate logic. If there were, then by the [double-negation translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%E2%80%93Gentzen_negative_translation) we could use it to decide classical predicate logic, which is known to be undecidable.

(Tableaux are not a decision procedure for classical predicate logic, because it is not guaranteed to terminate in the presence of quantifiers).

---

**Edit:** The question was changed to speak about intuitionistic *propositional* calculus. That is indeed decidable; one decision procedure is to search for a cut-free proof in the intuitionistic [sequent calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) LJ. Since every formula in a cut-free and quantifier-free proof is a subformula of the eventual conclusion, there are only finitely many possible sequents that don't repeat formulas to the left of the turnstile, so even a brute-force proof search will terminate.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sorry to say that what I really wanted to ask was about intuitionistic *propositional* logic.

Comment: Okay, answer edited.

Comment: You can also get the completeness semantically. If we fix a finite number of variables for propositional logic, there are only a finite number of possible Kripke frames for that set of variables, and therefore we can do an exhaustive search whether a particular formula is satisfied by every one of those frames.

Comment: Is there any decision procedure that can be carried out by hand?

Comment: @Pteromys: unless I am missing something, if there was a polynomial-time decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional logic, the double-negation translation would let us use this to make a polynomial-time decision procedure for classical propositional logic, and no such procedure is known to exist (if it does exist, then $P=NP$). So you can perform these decision procedures by hand, because they are effective, but they will not be very efficient.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Could you please elaborate on the method of enumerating Kripke frames?

Comment: @Pteromys: you'd have to check the exact wording of a completeness theorem, but it seems that since the completeness theorem works for "persistent" frames in which the truth values established in one world cannot change or become undefined in a later world, the are only finitely many possible persistent frames. Basically you have a labeled finite tree in which the root is labeled with a partial truth assignment and the assignment on each child node extends the assignment on its parent node.  There are only finitely many such trees for a finite set of variables.

Answer (score 13):

Even though you accepted Henning Makholm's answer already, this seemed likely to be of some use, and was too big for a comment, so I am posting it anyway.

I found some material related to your question on pages 33–34 of *Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism* by Sørensen and Urzyczyn. In particular (theorem 2.4.8 and surrounding discussion):

> A [intuitionistic propositional] formula of length $n$ is valid iff it is valid in all Heyting algebras of cardinality at most $2^{2^n}$.

This might be feasible to check by hand if $n<3$.
I think that by "length" here they mean "number of variables". They sketch the proof and refer the reader to Rasiowa and Sikorski *The Mathematics of Metamathematics* (Warsaw 1963) for details.

The next bit is perhaps more interesting:

> From … the above theorem, it follows that intuitionistic propositional logic is decidable. But the upper bound obtained this way (double exponential space) can be improved down to polynomial space, with help of other methods, see ….

This time the reference is R. Statman. "Intuitionistic propositional logic is polynomial-space complete." *Theoretical Computer Science*, 9:67–72, 1979.

I hope this is of some use.

Comment: I'll have a look at them after studying about using Heyting algebras as the models of intuitionist logic.  Do you know good references?  Most of textbooks I know of explain Kripke models, but not Heyting algebras.

Comment: Let me add that "intutionistic propositional logic with one variable" is decidable in linear time, while "intutionistic propositional logic with two variables" is Pspace-complete. The first result is the classical one by Rieger-Nishimura, and the second one is a recent result by Mikhail Rybakov.

Comment: @Pteromys I think the Sørensen-Urzyczyn book is a good introduction. Section 2.4 is specifically about Heyting algebras as models of intuitionistic logic. You may be able to find it online, since it was widely distributed before it was published by Springer. A Heyting algebra is more general than a Boolean algebra, but less general than a distributive lattice.

Comment: Note that we can't do any better than saying the problem can be solved in polynomial space (at least not without making a major breakthrough), since intuitionist propositional logic is PSPACE-complete.

Answer (score 13):

Gentzen was the first to show decidability. Papers about 1990 by Jörg Hudelmaier (giving an O(n log n)-space decision procedure) and by myself (Roy Dyckhoff) should be studied by anyone interested in using such a procedure. These show (following earlier work of Vorob'ev in 1950) how to avoid loop-checking in a root-first sequent calculus search. Avoiding back-tracking is a harder problem... The appropriate calculus G4ip is covered in the standard text, Basic Proof Theory.  The ILTP library at Potsdam (maintained by Jens Otten) links to implementations and classes of problems. Use of large Heyting algebras isn't really the best way to do it...

Comment: and, yes, the G4ip calculus is simple for the decision procedure to be carried out by hand.