# Algorithm to decide whether a proposition is constructively provable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics

To decide whether a propositional formula $P$ is classically provable, the completeness theorem gives an easy algorithm : simply test all finite boolean combinations of the variables of $P$. It is exponential in the number of variables, but it does finish in all cases.

Now completeness for constructive proofs means that we must test all evaluations of the variables of $P$ into all Heyting algebras, not just $\{0,1\}$. The open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ form such a Heyting algebra, which is infinite. So is there a constructive decision algorithm ?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136735/288417.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco You are right, this is a duplicate question. How can I close it ?