# Is it decidable whether a classically valid first-order formula is also intuitionistically valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuitionistic-logic, decidability

Intuitionistic first-order predicate logic is [not decidable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136737/448950) for arbitrary formulas.

However, suppose that we are given a formula of first-order predicate logic that is classically valid.  Is there a decision procedure that will determine whether it is also valid intuitionistically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restricting to classically valid formulas doesn't do anything here. Let $\psi$ be a fixed formula which is classically valid, but not intuitionistically. Now for a given formula $\phi$, consider $\psi \vee \phi$. This formula is classically valid, and it is intuitionistically valid if and only if $\phi$ was.

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks for the quick and clear reply.